# How to make a date limit in php?

Tags: php, date

How can I limit this date or print this date from the star_date to end_date?
ex.

```
$start_date="2011-05-15";//june 15 2011

$end_date="2011-07-30";//july -7,2011

The result should be.

$dates[]="2011-05-15";
$dates[]="2011-05-16";
$dates[]="2011-05-17";
$dates[]="2011-05-18";
$dates[]="....";
$dates[]="....";
$dates[]="....";
$dates[]="....";
until it reaches.
$dates[]="2011-07-30";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Loop thru all months in date range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155110/php-loop-thru-all-months-in-date-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$start_date = "2011-05-15";
$end_date = "2011-07-07";

$dates = array();
$stop = strtotime($end_date);
for($i = strtotime($start_date); $i <= $stop; $i += 86400)
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $i);
```

PS. I changed your July date to `07-07` to match up with your comment.

Comment: @mocca 86400 is the number of seconds in one day. The value in `$i` is in seconds, so I increment it by 86400 to get to the next day.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest take the start date as an object and keep adding 1 day (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) in a loop until you reach the end date.

```
<?php
$start_date = new DateTime('2011-05-15');
$end_date = new DateTime('2011-07-30');
while($end_date > $start_date)
{
   echo $start_date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
   $start_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
?>
```

The above code has not been tested.

Answer (score 2):

This could do it ...

```
$start_date = strtotime('2011-05-15'); //june 15 2011
$end_date = strtotime('2011-07-30'); //july -7,2011
$dates = array();
for ($i=$start_date; $i<=$end_date; $i+=86400) {
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d',$i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$start_date="2011-05-15";
$end_date="2011-07-30";
$date=$start_date;
while (strtotime($new_date) != strtotime($end_date))
{
   echo $new_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)))."<br>";
   $dates[]=$new_date;
   $date=$new_date;       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And another....

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$startDate='2011-05-15';
$endDate='2011-07-30';

$t1=strtotime($startDate);
$days=(strtotime($endDate)-$t1)/86400;

for($i=0;$i<=$days;$i++) $dates[]=date('Y-m-d',$t1+($i*86400));

print_r($dates);
```

And for the 'not very efficient but will do in most cases oneliner':

```
for($t=strtotime($startDate);$t<=strtotime($endDate);$t+=86400) $dates[]=date('Y-m-d',$t);
```

And one for those who know, the last for this mornings exercises:

```
$dates=array_map(create_function('$t','return date("Y-m-d",$t);'),range(strtotime($startDate),strtotime($endDate),86400));
```

Comment: yeah, but setting Los Angeles as the epicenter automatically adds an hour with traffic... (cringe)

Comment: @neokio sorry about that, I couldn't figure your timezone and LA was one of the first in the list...

Answer (score 1):

```
$start_date = strtotime('2011-05-15');
$end_date = strtotime('2011-07-30');
$dates = array();
for ($i = $start_date; $i<=$end_date; $i+= (strtotime('+1 day') - strtotime('now'))) {
   $dates[] = date('Y-m-d',$i);
}
```