# Generate date string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

Is there a way to generate all date strings between two timestamps?
For example, I have a earliest timestamp and a lastest timestamp of `1303887600(2011-04-27T00:00:00-07:00), 1325318400(2011-12-31T00:00:00-08:00)`, so I want from `2011-04-27` to `2011-12-31`.

If using a `for` loop to convert timestamp to date, there is a switch between daylight saving time.

Comment: Yes sure! But please try it yourself before you ask thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Return all dates between two dates in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Is there a simple way to loop between two dates and fill in missing values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755650/php-is-there-a-simple-way-to-loop-between-two-dates-and-fill-in-missing-values)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$temp_date = $start_date;
While($temp_date <= $end_date)
{
    print date("d-m-Y", strtotime($temp_date))
    $temp_date = $temp_date + 1 day;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for($i=1303887600;$i<=1325318400;$i++) echo date(DATE_ATOM,$i) . "<br />";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d","2010/12/24",new DateTimeZone("Europe/London")); 
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d","2012/01/05",new DateTimeZone("Europe/London")); 

$periodInterval = new DateInterval( "P1D" ); // 1-day, though can be more sophisticated rule 
$endDate->add( $periodInterval );
$period = new DatePeriod( $startDate, $periodInterval, $endDate ); 

foreach($period as $date){ 
   echo $date->format("Y-m-d") , PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Comment: Markdown why? Have I misunderstood the question?