# How to get exact average of n number of order in m number of months?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datepicker

Example:

```
$difference = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
$months = ($difference / 86400 / 30 );
```

Problem: But this way I never get exact average. Because I can’t sure for 30 days there can be 31 and 28 days months also.

Even I tried to divide by 12 month average but that also can’t work in every month selection cases
read first and
change according to ur own

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of days for certain month in certain year using this function:

[PHP Manual - cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

You can get number of days for whole year using, for example, this solution:

[Finding the total number of days in year](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Date-Time-Finding-The-Total-Number-of-Days-in-Year-P385.html)

Also, if you just want to get number of days for current month, you can use this:

```
date("t");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you after the number of months in a date range? If so, you could modify this previous answer to handle what you want:

[PHP: Loop through all months in a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155110/php-loop-thru-all-months-in-date-range)

To what I think you're after, you'd do something like this

```
$date_from = strtotime("2013-08-01");
$date_to = strtotime("2013-10-01");

$month_count = 0;
while ($date_from < $date_to) {
  $date_from = strtotime('+1 month', $date_from);
  $month_count++;
}

// month_count = number of months covered in the date range
```

Or, if you're just looking for the number of days in a date range, you could do something like this:

```
$date_from = strtotime("2013-08-01");
$date_to = strtotime("2013-08-28");
$diff = $date_to - $date_from;
$days_in_range = floor($diff / (60*60*24));

//days_in_range = 27
```

Not entirely sure what you're after from your question.