# List specific past month up to current month

Tags: php, loops, date

With these variables..

```
$month1  = 8;  // A month in the past
$month2  = date('n');  // Current month
```

...I need to a loop that outputs this:

```
August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March
```

8 is obviously the 8th month, hence August.

I realise the vars are using numeric representation, but the output needs to be a comma separated list of full textual representations of the month names.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: did you try something??

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560290/php-get-all-months-between-2-dates) may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$month1  = 8;  // A month in the past
$month2  = date('n') + 12; 

for ($i = $month2; $i >= $month1; $i--)
    $m[] = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, ($i % 12), 10));

$months = implode (",", $m);
print $months;
```

Comment: That returns the opposite and backwards: March,February,January,December,November,October,September,August

Comment: Why don't you just modify the for loop? like this: `for ($i = $month1; $i <= $month2; $i++)`

Comment: Perfect thanks. Have modified your original answer and accepeted it.