# monthname for loop inside if-else statement

Tags: php, date

I have this code that will print **name of month** up to current month, if the year is current year and print up to `december`,  if its not the current year.

The code is working, but I would like to ask:

- Is there any shortest code to get the same result?

---

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$current_month  = date('n'); 
$year=2015;


if ($year==$current_year )
{
for($m=1; $m<=$current_month; ++$m){
    $monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br />';
//print up to current month 
echo $monthName;
    }
}   
else
{

for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br />';
//print up to December
echo $monthName;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742998/how-to-list-all-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need two for loops. You just need check one if condition and set value for current month accordingly.

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$current_month = date('n'); 
$year=2015;

if($year!=$current_year)
  $current_month = 12;

for($m=1; $m<=$current_month; ++$m){
  $monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br />';
  //print up to current month 
  echo $monthName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to decide up front where you will end your list...

```
if ($year==$current_year ) {
   $endMonth=$current_month;
}
else {
   $endMonth=12;
}

for($m=1; $m<=$endMonth; ++$m){
    $monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br />';
    echo $monthName;
    }
```

You could abbreviate the first bit to...

```
   $endMonth=($year==$current_year)?$current_month:12;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one loop and you need to break loop using only one if condition for the current year.

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$current_month  = date('n');
$year=2017;

for ($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m) {
    if ($year==$current_year && $m>$current_month) {
        break;
    }
    $monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br />';
    echo $monthName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of use for loop 2 times you can use a max variable and put that in for loop...
I mean to say...

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$current_month  = date('n'); 
$year=2015;
if ($year==$current_year )$max= $current_month;
else $max = 12;
for($m=1; $m<=$max; ++$m){
    $monthName=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'<br />';
    echo $monthName;
}
```