# How to divided number based on date using php?

Tags: php

I have 2 variables called

`$joined_date = 2016-09-18` and

`$monthly_bill = 1200`

Now I want to show all months from joined date to today date with monthly bill. For example, the loop should show the bellow result :

```
2016-09-18        480 // Joined 18th and month end 30th = 12 days * (1200 / 30) 
2016-10-01        1200 
2016-11-01        1200 
2016-12-01        1200 
2017-01-01        1200
```

How can show this using php loop ?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense: You say monthly bill is 1200, but your examples say 1000.  Which is it?  Additionally, this is not a "Write the code for me" site.  Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Oh Sorry, about it. It's should be 1200

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Loop through all months in a date range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155110/php-loop-through-all-months-in-a-date-range)

Comment: @CD001 My question is bit different. I want show all months with full number or fraction number.

Comment: Not massively different as you're only spaffing out the partial month for the first one... but OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //cal_days_in_month : Return the number of days in a month for a given year and calendar  

----------

<?php
$join_date="2016-09-18";
$begin = new DateTime($join_date); // value is : 2016-09-18
$monthly_bill = 1200;
$date=$begin->format('d');
$month=$begin->format('m');
$year=$begin->format("Y");
$ndays=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
if($date>1)
{
    $totaldays=$ndays-$date;
}
else{
    $totaldays=$ndays;
}
$paidbill=$totaldays * ($monthly_bill / $ndays);
echo $paidbill."<br/>";


?>
```

Comment: Hi Devi, let me check it.

Comment: Somehow the calculation is not showing actual monthly bill in my actual php loop. In my loop I am getting all users monthly bill which is : 350, 250, 150, 300, 200 and 100. (6 users). But the result is not correct

Comment: which is 140, 350, 350, 350, 350 for the 1st user

Comment: Can you post your code i.e., how you are looping for every user?

Comment: It's a bit long while loop

Comment: But if your given code is run perfectly then my loop will be shown correct amount. :)

Comment: I was given code for all months from start date to end date to single user

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Yes, I am checking it.

Comment: Now It's showing only fraction monthly bill for each user

Comment: My Overall goal is to general a monthly bill for each month. So for 1st user you see that joined date is `2016-09-18` and bill is e.g `$100`. So `2016-09-18` bill will be `40` and then rest of the each month will be `$100`

Comment: What fraction value are you getting?. give your result screen again.

Comment: It's 140, 225.8064516129, 150, 9.6774193548387, 6.4516129032258, 100

Comment: You $monthly_bill values 350,250,150... to dates 2016-09-18,2016-08-03,2016-07-01. i.e., (1)userID:php2122,$monthly_bill:350,date:2016-09-18,result:140..(2) 2nd user:newId,,$monthly_bill:250,date:2016-08-03,result:225.806451613..

Comment: check what user, amount and date are passing in every iteration of loop along with result by displaying in browser, then u will know.

Comment: Hi you can check the while loop result on my screenshot.. Here `connected` column shows the joined date and `Bill` column shows the monthly bill of each user.

Comment: Yes. I checked it. you are getting the correct result. 140, 225.8064516129, 150, 9.6774193548387, 6.4516129032258, 100 are not for single user. you displayed the result in the order same as table row order.